# How to color new list record like outlook do?

Tags: list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

Is there any possibility to color new record on SharePoint list like outlook new emails?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online.?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint online, you can use JSON formatting to customize how fields/list views in SharePoint lists are displayed.

For more information check below documentations:

1. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

Also check [List formatting GitHub repository](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting) where you can find different column/view samples to get started with JSON formatting.

Comment: Another great guide is https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-pnp-blog/getting-started-with-sharepoint-s-custom-column-formatting/ba-p/2207937

Comment: Hi Jacko21, did you try my suggestions? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way.